# Docker volume mount issue to a mounted folder

Tags: docker, unix, docker-compose, mount, mounted-volumes

We have mounted a folder in a Linux machine to our docker container application using (docker-compose)
volumes:
- /mnt/share:/mnt/share

The /mnt/share is a mounted folder in the machine(Not a real folder in the machine, its our file server). IF for some reason that mount is lost and then remounted again.
The application running in the docker container is not having access to the mounted folder until the container is restarted.

Comment: Whatever you use to remount the volume, you can use to restart the containers... containers are designed to be restarted a lot.

Comment: @root but the team implementing the remouting logic is not ready to write the script to restart the container :( . So we implemented it in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution helped me to continue.
I wrote a script to check whether the folder exists.
The script is then called a command in the docker-compose file.

```
   version:"3" 
  services:
   flowable-task-handler:
    build: flowable-task-handler  
    ports:
    - "8085:8085"
    command: bash -c "/wait_for_file_mount.sh /mnt/share/fileshares/ && java -jar /app.jar"
```

wait_for_file_mount.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# Used to check whether the mount folder is ready for flowable to use
mountedfolder="$1"
until [  -d "$mountedfolder" ];
 do sleep 2;
  echo error "Mounted folder not found : $mountedfolder";
   done;
```

Its a spring boot application. I have removed the entrypoint in the DockerFile and application is started using the command in docker compose(java -jar /app.jar")

Answer (score 6):

You might want to use to use a Volume Driver instead of bind-mounting a local filesystem.
See [Share data among machines](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#share-data-among-machines)

Without knowing more about your environment it is impossible to give a more detailed answer. It would be helpful to know if your container runs in a AWS data center or if you use nfsv3, nfsv4 or cifs for mounting.

Comment: Just an additional comment to add to this answer, if for some reason you can't use a volume driver, another good option is to treat your network mounts as "removable storage" and use something like autofs to automatically reconnect them on next access.

https://wiki.debian.org/AutoFs

Answer (score 0):

defining the mount propagation as ":shared" should fix this:

-v /autofs:/autofs:shared \

not sure about docker-compose - I don't really use that. but you can define a docker volume with mount propagation and put this into your DC file.